# Disabling MySQL strict mode using nano sudo on Mac

Tags: mysql, linux, database, nano, my.cnf

I created the file my.cnf with this:

> [mysqld]

> secure_file_priv=""

and when I tried to load data, I found that MySQL does not allow me to load columns with empty rows. So I decided to remove the restriction: STRICT_TRANS_TABLES.

Then I tried to edit my.cnf file using nano sudo on Mac terminal:

> sudo nano /etc/my.cnf

Then I press command+O(Write Out). Next I write down a line:

> sql_mode= ""

My question is: what should I do next? Append? But when I pressed alt+A, there is nothing happen? Also, is there any problem in my operations?

[image]

Comment: I don't get it, are you asking how to use nano editor? if so, check the documentation.

Comment: I would like to edit the existing my.cnf file I have created and add this line: sql_mode= "". Not sure how to do it correctly.

Comment: you should ask in Super User community, but if you don't' know how to edit a file, you should check the editor (nano) documentation, or use a differente editor.